# Change 'Choose an Option...' text Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, phtml

On a **configurable product** I would like to **change the text 'Choose an Option...' to 'Select an Option...'**

I have attempted to change the i18n translation file within my theme, and cleared cache - however this has not worked.

Can anyone **please advise of the file that needs updating to change this text**?

Comment: Try System -> Cache Management > Flush Static Files Cache for i18n translations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to change the text either using language file ( recommended )  or in template file :

**Lanuage File CSV :**
copy below file to your theme folder and update translation as required.

/var/www/html/magento.com/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/i18n/en_US.csv

**or Change in template file** 
( not recommended as this would create issue while adding multiple-lanuages / translation, so you need to update this in all _csv files:

copy below file and add in your theme folder ( /package/theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml )

`/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml`

Comment: Thanks Naveed. I used the second step. As translation file update did not work for me.

Comment: Hi Naveed... in fact the second option still did not appear to work... on loading the page it quickly flashes 'select an option...' before going back to 'choose an option...' arrgh. Any advice please?

Comment: @YorkieMagento hey, did you find any solution?

Comment: Sorry @FenaShah I did not. Worth a try using the solutions provided though, to see if it works in your case?

Comment: @YorkieMagento did it finally :)

Comment: How did you do it @FenaShah?

Comment: By making changes on js only. @YorkieMagento

Comment: Perfect Solution!

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite the template file add in your theme folder

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

Change the text "Choose an Option"...' to "Select an Option..."

Run the following command

1. php bin/magento cache:clean
2. php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I did this Rama, it flashes up as 'select an option' for a split second in the front end, and then changes back to 'choose an option'... any suggestions?

Comment: I am trying but not overtie configurable.php if you have idea reply me and in first  option value  by default  show in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the function "getJsonConfig" which is found in magento/module-configurable-product/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php

```
$config = [
        'attributes' => $attributesData['attributes'],
        'template' => str_replace('%s', '<%- data.price %>', $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat()),
        'currencyFormat' => $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat(),
        'optionPrices' => $this->getOptionPrices(),
        'priceFormat' => $this->localeFormat->getPriceFormat(),
        'prices' => $this->variationPrices->getFormattedPrices($this->getProduct()->getPriceInfo()),
        'productId' => $currentProduct->getId(),
        'chooseText' => __('Choose an Option...'),
        'images' => $this->getOptionImages(),
        'index' => isset($options['index']) ? $options['index'] : [],
    ];
```

Create a module and overwrite it